# Wordpress migration with blank admin area

Tags: php, wordpress

I have migrate a wordpress instalation from a server to another server and I'm not able to access the admin area.

I have set the DEBUG to True but I only get a blank page after login with Warnings.

The new url is http://mr.izigo.net/

user: admin
pass: admin

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found here http://www.farinspace.com/wordpress-migration/ the solution to the problem, apparently after a migration, and when the instalation has plug-ins, we need to remove the related options.

I had done the URL replaces, but not the plug-in DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` = 'active_plugins' command.

After that, I had to reactivate the plug-ins and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting error messages? What are they?

Does the login name and password in the new wp-config.php file match the old one?

Comment: Hi, thanks. You can check at http://mr.izigo.net/wp-login.php with admin/admin I get Warnings and Notices.